# std::out of range in a noxim code

Tags: c++, systemc

Im starting with some SystemC coding and i'm trying to use a Network-on-chip simulator called "Noxim", which i've heard is very smooth and simple. However, im getting this common error when I'm trying to "make" some part of the simulation

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr
Abort
```

I think it comes from a cpp code, which I DO NOT own and, sincerely, dont fully understand. The code can be found bellow, and the full Noxim distribution can be found here: https://github.com/alexayin/Noxim

The code is at Noxim/other/

Noxim_explorer.cpp and sim.cfg are strongly related to the lab im trying to do.

Please, if someone has solved this problem or have any idea, it would be very helpful.

FOR THE RECORD: I got stucked when trying to follow this lab http://access.ee.ntu.edu.tw/noxim/Lab2.pdf, 'cause I couldnt get any info in the matlab file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define DEFAULT_KEY          "default"
#define AGGREGATION_KEY      "aggregation"
#define EXPLORER_KEY         "explorer"
#define SIMULATOR_LABEL      "simulator"
#define REPETITIONS_LABEL    "repetitions"
#define TMP_DIR_LABEL        "tmp"

#define DEF_SIMULATOR        "./noxim"
#define DEF_REPETITIONS      5
#define DEF_TMP_DIR          "./"

#define TMP_FILE_NAME        ".noxim_explorer.tmp"

#define RPACKETS_LABEL       "% Total received packets:"
#define RFLITS_LABEL         "% Total received flits:"
#define AVG_DELAY_LABEL      "% Global average delay (cycles):"
#define AVG_THROUGHPUT_LABEL "% Global average throughput (flits/cycle):"
#define THROUGHPUT_LABEL     "% Throughput (flits/cycle/IP):"
#define MAX_DELAY_LABEL      "% Max delay (cycles):"
#define TOTAL_ENERGY_LABEL   "% Total energy (J):"

#define MATLAB_VAR_NAME      "data"
#define MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH  15

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef unsigned int uint;

// parameter values
typedef vector<string> TParameterSpace;

// parameter name, parameter space
typedef map<string, TParameterSpace> TParametersSpace;

// parameter name, parameter value
typedef vector<pair<string, string> > TConfiguration;

typedef vector<TConfiguration> TConfigurationSpace;

struct TExplorerParams
{
  string simulator;
  string tmp_dir;
  int    repetitions;
};

struct TSimulationResults
{
  double       avg_delay;
  double       throughput;
  double       avg_throughput;
  double       max_delay;
  double       total_energy;
  unsigned int rpackets;
  unsigned int rflits;
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

double GetCurrentTime()
{
  struct timeval tv;

  gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

  return tv.tv_sec + (tv.tv_usec * 1.0e-6);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void TimeToFinish(double elapsed_sec,
          int completed, int total,
          int& hours, int& minutes, int &seconds)
{
  double total_time_sec = (elapsed_sec * total)/completed;
  double remain_time_sec = total_time_sec - elapsed_sec;

  seconds = (int)remain_time_sec % 60;
  minutes = ((int)remain_time_sec / 60) % 60;
  hours   = (int)remain_time_sec / 3600;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool IsComment(const string& s)
{
  return (s == "" || s.at(0) == '%');
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

string TrimLeftAndRight(const string& s)
{
  int len = s.length();

  int i, j;
  for (i=0; i<len && s.at(i) == ' '; i++) ;
  for (j=len-1; j>=0 && s.at(j) == ' '; j--) ;

  return s.substr(i,j-i+1);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool ExtractParameter(const string& s, string& parameter)
{
  uint i = s.find("[");

  if (i != string::npos)
    {
      uint j = s.rfind("]");

      if (j != string::npos)
    {
      parameter = s.substr(i+1, j-i-1);
      return true;
    }
    }

  return false;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool GetNextParameter(ifstream& fin, string& parameter)
{
  bool found = false;

  while (!fin.eof() && !found)
    {
      string s;
      getline(fin, s);

      if (!IsComment(s))
    found = ExtractParameter(s, parameter);
    }

  return found;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------w

string MakeStopParameterTag(const string& parameter)
{
  string sparameter = "[/" + parameter + "]";

  return sparameter;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool ManagePlainParameterSet(ifstream& fin,
                 const string& parameter, 
                 TParametersSpace& params_space,
                 string& error_msg)
{
  string str_stop = MakeStopParameterTag(parameter);
  bool   stop = false;

  while (!fin.eof() && !stop)
    {
      string s;
      getline(fin, s);

      if (!IsComment(s))
    {
      if (s.find(str_stop) != string::npos)
        stop = true;
      else
        params_space[parameter].push_back(TrimLeftAndRight(s));
    }
    }

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool ExpandInterval(const string& sint,
            TParameterSpace& ps,
            string& error_msg)
{
  istringstream iss(sint);

  double min, max, step;

  iss >> min;
  iss >> max;
  iss >> step;

  string param_suffix;
  getline(iss, param_suffix);

  for (double v=min; v<=max; v+=step)
    {
      ostringstream oss;
      oss << v;
      ps.push_back(oss.str() + param_suffix);
    }

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool ManageCompressedParameterSet(ifstream& fin,
                  const string& parameter, 
                  TParametersSpace& params_space,
                  string& error_msg)
{
  string str_stop = MakeStopParameterTag(parameter);
  bool   stop = false;

  while (!fin.eof() && !stop)
    {
      string s;
      getline(fin, s);

      if (!IsComment(s))
    {
      if (s.find(str_stop) != string::npos)
        stop = true;
      else    
        {
          if (!ExpandInterval(s, params_space[parameter], error_msg))
        return false;
        }
    }
    }

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool ManageParameter(ifstream& fin,
             const string& parameter, 
             TParametersSpace& params_space,
             string& error_msg)
{
  bool err;

  if (parameter == "pir")
    err = ManageCompressedParameterSet(fin, parameter, params_space, error_msg);
  else
    err = ManagePlainParameterSet(fin, parameter, params_space, error_msg);

  return err;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool ParseConfigurationFile(const string& fname,
                TParametersSpace& params_space,
                string& error_msg)
{
  ifstream fin(fname.c_str(), ios::in);

  if (!fin)
    {
      error_msg = "Cannot open " + fname;
      return false;
    }

  while (!fin.eof())
    {
      string parameter;

      if ( GetNextParameter(fin, parameter) )
    {
      if (!ManageParameter(fin, parameter, params_space, error_msg))
        return false;
    }
    }

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool LastCombination(const vector<pair<int,int> >& indexes)
{
  for (uint i=0; i<indexes.size(); i++)
    if (indexes[i].first < indexes[i].second-1)
      return false;

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool IncrementCombinatorialIndexes(vector<pair<int,int> >& indexes)
{
  for (uint i=0; i<indexes.size(); i++)
    {
      if (indexes[i].first < indexes[i].second - 1)
    {
      indexes[i].first++;
      return true;
    }
      indexes[i].first = 0; 
    }

  return false;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TConfigurationSpace Explore(const TParametersSpace& params_space)

{
  TConfigurationSpace conf_space;

  vector<pair<int,int> > indexes; // <index, max_index>

  for (TParametersSpace::const_iterator psi=params_space.begin();
       psi!=params_space.end(); psi++)
      indexes.push_back(pair<int,int>(0, psi->second.size()));

  do 
    {
      int i = 0;
      TConfiguration conf;
      for (TParametersSpace::const_iterator psi=params_space.begin();
       psi!=params_space.end(); psi++)
    {
      conf.push_back( pair<string,string>(psi->first, 
                          psi->second[indexes[i].first]));    
      i++;
    }
      conf_space.push_back(conf);
    } 
  while (IncrementCombinatorialIndexes(indexes));

  return conf_space;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool RemoveParameter(TParametersSpace& params_space, 
             const string& param_name,
             TParameterSpace& param_space,
             string& error_msg)
{
  TParametersSpace::iterator i = params_space.find(param_name);

  if (i == params_space.end())
    {
      error_msg = "Cannot extract parameter '" + param_name + "'";
      return false;
    }

  param_space = params_space[param_name];
  params_space.erase(i);

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool RemoveAggregateParameters(TParametersSpace& params_space, 
                   TParameterSpace&  aggregated_params,
                   TParametersSpace& aggragated_params_space,
                   string& error_msg)
{
  for (uint i=0; i<aggregated_params.size(); i++)
    {
      string param_name = aggregated_params[i];
      TParameterSpace param_space;
      if (!RemoveParameter(params_space, param_name, param_space, error_msg))
    return false;

      aggragated_params_space[param_name] = param_space;
    }

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

string ParamValue2Cmd(const pair<string,string>& pv)
{
  string cmd;

  if (pv.first == "topology")
    {
      istringstream iss(pv.second);

      int  width, height;
      char times;
      iss >> width >> times >> height;

      ostringstream oss;
      oss << "-dimx " << width << " -dimy " << height;

      cmd = oss.str();
    }
  else
    cmd = "-" + pv.first + " " + pv.second;

  return cmd;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

string Configuration2CmdLine(const TConfiguration& conf)
{
  string cl;

  for (uint i=0; i<conf.size(); i++)
    cl = cl + ParamValue2Cmd(conf[i]) + " ";

  return cl;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

string Configuration2FunctionName(const TConfiguration& conf)
{
  string fn;

  for (uint i=0; i<conf.size(); i++)
    fn = fn + conf[i].first + "_" + conf[i].second + "__";

  // Replace " ", "-", ".", "/" with "_"
  int len = fn.length();
  for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    if (fn.at(i) == ' ' || fn.at(i) == '.' || fn.at(i) == '-' || fn.at(i) == '/')
      fn[i] = '_';

  return fn;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool ExtractExplorerParams(const TParameterSpace& explorer_params,
               TExplorerParams& eparams,
               string& error_msg)
{
  eparams.simulator   = DEF_SIMULATOR;
  eparams.tmp_dir     = DEF_TMP_DIR;
  eparams.repetitions = DEF_REPETITIONS;

  for (uint i=0; i<explorer_params.size(); i++)
    {
      istringstream iss(explorer_params[i]);

      string label;
      iss >> label;

      if (label == SIMULATOR_LABEL)
    iss >> eparams.simulator;
      else if (label == REPETITIONS_LABEL)
    iss >> eparams.repetitions;
      else if (label == TMP_DIR_LABEL)
    iss >> eparams.tmp_dir;
      else
    {
      error_msg = "Invalid explorer option '" + label + "'";
      return false;
    }
    }

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool PrintHeader(const string& fname,
         const TExplorerParams& eparams,
         const string& def_cmd_line, const string& conf_cmd_line, 
         ofstream& fout, 
         string& error_msg)
{
  fout.open(fname.c_str(), ios::out);
  if (!fout)
    {
      error_msg = "Cannot create " + fname;
      return false;
    }

  fout << "% fname: " << fname << endl
       << "% " << eparams.simulator << " "
       << conf_cmd_line << " " << def_cmd_line
       << endl << endl;

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool PrintMatlabFunction(const string& mfname,
             ofstream& fout, 
             string& error_msg)
{
  fout << "function [max_pir, max_throughput, min_delay] = " << mfname << "(symbol)" << endl
       << endl;

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool ReadResults(const string& fname, 
         TSimulationResults& sres, 
         string& error_msg)
{
  ifstream fin(fname.c_str(), ios::in);
  if (!fin)
    {
      error_msg = "Cannot read " + fname;
      return false;
    }

  int nread = 0;
  while (!fin.eof())
    {
      string line;
      getline(fin, line);

      uint pos;

      pos = line.find(RPACKETS_LABEL);
      if (pos != string::npos) 
    {
      nread++;
      istringstream iss(line.substr(pos + string(RPACKETS_LABEL).size()));
      iss >> sres.rpackets;
      continue;
    }

      pos = line.find(RFLITS_LABEL);
      if (pos != string::npos) 
    {
      nread++;
      istringstream iss(line.substr(pos + string(RFLITS_LABEL).size()));
      iss >> sres.rflits;
      continue;
    }

      pos = line.find(AVG_DELAY_LABEL);
      if (pos != string::npos) 
    {
      nread++;
      istringstream iss(line.substr(pos + string(AVG_DELAY_LABEL).size()));
      iss >> sres.avg_delay;
      continue;
    }

      pos = line.find(AVG_THROUGHPUT_LABEL);
      if (pos != string::npos) 
    {
      nread++;
      istringstream iss(line.substr(pos + string(AVG_THROUGHPUT_LABEL).size()));
      iss >> sres.avg_throughput;
      continue;
    }

      pos = line.find(THROUGHPUT_LABEL);
      if (pos != string::npos) 
    {
      nread++;
      istringstream iss(line.substr(pos + string(THROUGHPUT_LABEL).size()));
      iss >> sres.throughput;
      continue;
    }

      pos = line.find(MAX_DELAY_LABEL);
      if (pos != string::npos) 
    {
      nread++;
      istringstream iss(line.substr(pos + string(MAX_DELAY_LABEL).size()));
      iss >> sres.max_delay;
      continue;
    }

      pos = line.find(TOTAL_ENERGY_LABEL);
      if (pos != string::npos) 
    {
      nread++;
      istringstream iss(line.substr(pos + string(TOTAL_ENERGY_LABEL).size()));
      iss >> sres.total_energy;
      continue;
    }
    }

  if (nread != 7)
    {
      error_msg = "Output file " + fname + " corrupted";
      return false;
    }

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool RunSimulation(const string& cmd_base,
           const string& tmp_dir,
           TSimulationResults& sres, 
           string& error_msg)
{
  string tmp_fname = tmp_dir + TMP_FILE_NAME;
  //  string cmd = cmd_base + " >& " + tmp_fname; // this works only with csh and bash
  string cmd = cmd_base + " >" + tmp_fname + " 2>&1"; // this works with sh, csh, and bash!

  cout << cmd << endl;
  system(cmd.c_str());
  if (!ReadResults(tmp_fname, sres, error_msg))
    return false;

  string rm_cmd = string("rm -f ") + tmp_fname;
  system(rm_cmd.c_str());

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

string ExtractFirstField(const string& s)
{
  istringstream iss(s);

  string sfirst;

  iss >> sfirst;

  return sfirst;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool RunSimulations(double start_time,
            pair<uint,uint>& sim_counter,
            const string& cmd, const string& tmp_dir, const int repetitions,
            const TConfiguration& aggr_conf, 
            ofstream& fout, 
            string& error_msg)
{
  int    h, m, s;

  for (int i=0; i<repetitions; i++)
    {
      cout << "# simulation " << (++sim_counter.first) << " of " << sim_counter.second;
      if (i != 0)
    cout << ", estimated time to finish " << h << "h " << m << "m " << s << "s";
      cout << endl;

      TSimulationResults sres;
      if (!RunSimulation(cmd, tmp_dir, sres, error_msg))
    return false;

      double current_time = GetCurrentTime();
      TimeToFinish(current_time-start_time, sim_counter.first, sim_counter.second, h, m, s);

      // Print aggragated parameters
      fout << "  ";
      for (uint i=0; i<aggr_conf.size(); i++)
    fout << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << ExtractFirstField(aggr_conf[i].second); // this fix the problem with pir
      // fout << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << aggr_conf[i].second;

      // Print results;
      fout << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << sres.avg_delay
       << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << sres.throughput
       << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << sres.max_delay
       << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << sres.total_energy
       << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << sres.rpackets
       << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << sres.rflits 
       << endl;
    }

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool PrintMatlabVariableBegin(const TParametersSpace& aggragated_params_space, 
                  ofstream& fout, string& error_msg)
{
  fout << MATLAB_VAR_NAME << " = [" << endl;
  fout << "% ";
  for (TParametersSpace::const_iterator i=aggragated_params_space.begin();
       i!=aggragated_params_space.end(); i++)
    fout << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << i->first;

  fout << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << "avg_delay"
       << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << "throughput"
       << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << "max_delay"
       << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << "total_energy"
       << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << "rpackets"
       << setw(MATRIX_COLUMN_WIDTH) << "rflits";

  fout << endl;

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool GenMatlabCode(const string& var_name,
           const int fig_no,
           const int repetitions, const int column,
           ofstream& fout, string& error_msg)
{
  fout << var_name << " = [];" << endl
       << "for i = 1:rows/" << repetitions << "," << endl
       << "   ifirst = (i - 1) * " << repetitions << " + 1;" << endl
       << "   ilast  = ifirst + " << repetitions << " - 1;" << endl
       << "   tmp = " << MATLAB_VAR_NAME << "(ifirst:ilast, cols-6+" << column << ");" << endl
       << "   avg = mean(tmp);" << endl
       << "   [h sig ci] = ttest(tmp, 0.1);" << endl
       << "   ci = (ci(2)-ci(1))/2;" << endl
       << "   " << var_name << " = [" << var_name << "; " << MATLAB_VAR_NAME << "(ifirst, 1:cols-6), avg ci];" << endl
       << "end" << endl
       << endl;

  fout << "figure(" << fig_no << ");" << endl
       << "hold on;" << endl
       << "plot(" << var_name << "(:,1), " << var_name << "(:,2), symbol);" << endl
       << endl;

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool GenMatlabCodeSaturationAnalysis(const string& var_name,
                     ofstream& fout, string& error_msg)
{

  fout << endl 
       << "%-------- Saturation Analysis -----------" << endl
       << "slope=[];"  << endl
       << "for i=2:size(" << var_name << "_throughput,1),"  << endl
       << "    slope(i-1) = (" << var_name << "_throughput(i,2)-" << var_name << "_throughput(i-1,2))/(" << var_name << "_throughput(i,1)-" << var_name << "_throughput(i-1,1));"  << endl
       << "end"  << endl
       << endl
       << "for i=2:size(slope,2),"  << endl
       << "    if slope(i) < (0.95*mean(slope(1:i)))"  << endl
       << "        max_pir = " << var_name << "_throughput(i, 1);"  << endl
       << "        max_throughput = " << var_name << "_throughput(i, 2);"  << endl
       << "        min_delay = " << var_name << "_delay(i, 2);"  << endl
       << "        break;"  << endl
       << "    end"  << endl
       << "end"  << endl;

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool PrintMatlabVariableEnd(const int repetitions,
                ofstream& fout, string& error_msg)
{
  fout << "];" << endl << endl;

  fout << "rows = size(" << MATLAB_VAR_NAME << ", 1);" << endl
       << "cols = size(" << MATLAB_VAR_NAME << ", 2);" << endl
       << endl;

  if (!GenMatlabCode(string(MATLAB_VAR_NAME) + "_delay", 1,
             repetitions, 1, fout, error_msg))
    return false;

  if (!GenMatlabCode(string(MATLAB_VAR_NAME) + "_throughput", 2,
             repetitions, 2, fout, error_msg))
    return false;

  if (!GenMatlabCode(string(MATLAB_VAR_NAME) + "_maxdelay", 3,
             repetitions, 3, fout, error_msg))
    return false;

  if (!GenMatlabCode(string(MATLAB_VAR_NAME) + "_totalenergy", 4,
             repetitions, 4, fout, error_msg))
    return false;

  if (!GenMatlabCodeSaturationAnalysis(string(MATLAB_VAR_NAME), fout, error_msg))
    return false;

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool RunSimulations(const TConfigurationSpace& conf_space,
            const TParameterSpace&     default_params,
            const TParametersSpace&    aggragated_params_space,
            const TParameterSpace&     explorer_params,
            string&                    error_msg)
{
  TExplorerParams eparams;
  if (!ExtractExplorerParams(explorer_params, eparams, error_msg))
    return false;

  // Make dafault parameters string
  string def_cmd_line;
  for (uint i=0; i<default_params.size(); i++)
    def_cmd_line = def_cmd_line + default_params[i] + " ";

  // Explore configuration space
  TConfigurationSpace aggr_conf_space = Explore(aggragated_params_space);

  pair<uint,uint> sim_counter(0, conf_space.size() * aggr_conf_space.size() * eparams.repetitions);

  double start_time = GetCurrentTime();
  for (uint i=0; i<conf_space.size(); i++)
    {
      string conf_cmd_line = Configuration2CmdLine(conf_space[i]);

      string   mfname = Configuration2FunctionName(conf_space[i]);
      string   fname  = mfname + ".m";
      ofstream fout;
      if (!PrintHeader(fname, eparams, 
               def_cmd_line, conf_cmd_line, fout, error_msg))
    return false;

      if (!PrintMatlabFunction(mfname, fout, error_msg))
    return false;

      if (!PrintMatlabVariableBegin(aggragated_params_space, fout, error_msg))
    return false;

      for (uint j=0; j<aggr_conf_space.size(); j++)
    {
      string aggr_cmd_line = Configuration2CmdLine(aggr_conf_space[j]);
      /*
      string cmd = eparams.simulator + " "
        + def_cmd_line + " "
        + conf_cmd_line + " "
        + aggr_cmd_line;
      */
      string cmd = eparams.simulator + " "
            + aggr_cmd_line + " "
        + def_cmd_line + " "
        + conf_cmd_line;

      if (!RunSimulations(start_time,
                  sim_counter, cmd, eparams.tmp_dir, eparams.repetitions,
                  aggr_conf_space[j], fout, error_msg))
        return false;
    }

      if (!PrintMatlabVariableEnd(eparams.repetitions, fout, error_msg))
    return false;
    }

  return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool RunSimulations(const string& script_fname,
            string&       error_msg)
{
  TParametersSpace ps;

  if (!ParseConfigurationFile(script_fname, ps, error_msg))
    return false;


  TParameterSpace default_params;
  if (!RemoveParameter(ps, DEFAULT_KEY, default_params, error_msg))
    cout << "Warning: " << error_msg << endl;


  TParameterSpace  aggregated_params;
  TParametersSpace aggragated_params_space;
  if (!RemoveParameter(ps, AGGREGATION_KEY, aggregated_params, error_msg))
    cout << "Warning: " << error_msg << endl;
  else
    if (!RemoveAggregateParameters(ps, aggregated_params, 
                  aggragated_params_space, error_msg))
      return false;

  TParameterSpace explorer_params;
  if (!RemoveParameter(ps, EXPLORER_KEY, explorer_params, error_msg))
    cout << "Warning: " << error_msg << endl;

  TConfigurationSpace conf_space = Explore(ps);

  if (!RunSimulations(conf_space, default_params, 
              aggragated_params_space, explorer_params, error_msg))
    return false;


  return true;
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2)
    {
      cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <cfg file> [<cfg file>]" << endl;
      return -1;
    }

  for (int i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
      string fname(argv[i]);
      cout << "# Exploring configuration space " << fname << endl;

      string error_msg;

      if (!RunSimulations(fname, error_msg))
    cout << "Error: " << error_msg << endl;

      cout << endl;
    }

  return 0;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

U are probably using a 64 bit pc

At Noxim_explorer.cpp

change

///////////////////////////////

uint pos;

pos = line.find(RPACKETS_LABEL);

///////////////////////////////

to ...

///////////////////////////////

std::size_t pos = line.find(RPACKETS_LABEL);

///////////////////////////////

It should work .. and generate the matlab file